# Need to swap the -(minus) sign for only numbers and not text for a given row

Tags: sed

I have a input in which delimeter is `<;|` like given below:-

```
1-<;|3-Text <;|3.13-<;|0.28-<;|9
0.12-<;|2-Text <;|3.99-<;|4.11-<;|6
0.13-<;|3-Text <;|8.13-<;|3.98-<;|3
```

My expected output should be:-

```
-1<;|3-Text <;|-3.13<;|-0.28<;|9 
-0.12<;|2-Text <;|-3.99<;|-4.11<;|6
-0.13<;|3-Text <;|-8.13<;|-3.98<;|3
```

Here, I would like to bring the minus sign in front of only integer or decimal value and not for text field. The columns are not fixed and can be of any order. I am trying to use `sed` command but not successful with it. Please help me in this scenario.

Comment: `sed 's/\([0-9.]\+\)-</-\1</g'`

Comment: Your examples include: `1-<;|3-Text <;|`.  Will `Text` always follow the number?  Or, could your input contain `1-<;|Text 3-<;|`?

Comment: The input can contain Text 3- or 3- Anytext or 3-Anytext.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\+\)\(\.[[:digit:]]*\)\{0,1\}-\(\W\)/-\1\2\3/g'
```

GNU version of `sed` is needed in order to match "non-word" character after `-` with `\W`. You can simulate this with non-gnu version using `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

If `-` should not be changed also in case it precedes space than just add space to previous pattern, so:

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\+\)\(\.[[:digit:]]*\)\{0,1\}-\([^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]\)/-\1\2\3/g'
```

Comment: With non-gnu, you should be able to use `[^[:alnum:]_]`

Comment: Can you please share the actual usage of this in the command.

Comment: Thanks 

sed 's/([[:digit:]]+)(.[[:digit:]]*){0,1}-([^a-zA-Z0-9_ ])/-\1\2\3/g' is working. But the only case this fails is when there is only a whitespace behind the minus sign for other numeric fields it does not swap.

For eg:- echo "0.11- <;|3- Test <;|3.13-<;|" | sed 's/([[:digit:]]+)(.[[:digit:]]*){0,1}-([^a-zA-Z0-9_ ])/-\1\2\3/g'

output is 0.11- <;|3- Test <;|-3.13<;|

Comment: So perhaps better match delimiter `<;|` exactly after minus and any number of spaces: `sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\+\)\(\.[[:digit:]]*\)\{0,1\}-\(\s*<;|\)/-\1\2\3/g'`